# How to avoid multiple vscode server being installed?

Tags: vscode-remote

I connect to my Raspberry Pi (running 32-bit Raspbian) using VSCode remote ssh from a Linux PC. However, each time I turn on my machine and do connection, it always re-download and reinstall a new server instance in Raspberry Pi's `~/.vscode-server/bin`, resulting in many server folders and hard disk (SD card) occupation. How to avoid that?